# Не срабатывает пpостейший скрипт на событие .scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 100) {
                alert("100!");
            } 
        });

    });
</script>
```

Почему когда я прокручиваю страницу, не срабатывает алерт ?

Comment: Может быть, вместо `<body>` прокручивается что-то с `overflow:auto` или `overflow:scroll` внутри?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Явно обратитесь к window:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
      alert("100!");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>
1<br>1<br>
```